# pdf image is imported without x and y axes label

Tags: graphics, pdf

I am trying to import a pdf image into Latex with the below code, however, the image appears without any x and y axes labels. Not sure what is the problem.  [Here is a link to the pdf file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hrz6cqr0qqc96v/gdp.pdf?dl=0)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{file}
        \caption{UK GDP Growth Rate}
        \label{fig:gdpplot}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, the labels are here: http://cl.ly/aZIn

Comment: What compiler do you use? The MWE works as expected using both `PDFLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: I am on Mac OS 10.10.2 and PDFLaTeX is the compiler I am using

Comment: Are you sure it's not only a display problem? Sometimes very fine lines are not displayed at small magnifications. Did you try to zoom in to the generated page? **EDIT**: Sorry, it's about the *labels*, not *ticks*...

Comment: @Habi Yes, as the graph just above it in my file works very fine.

Comment: @Habi got it now. When I opened the file externally it worked very fine. The fact that kind of the same graph above it works fine confused me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a PDF viewer issue.